# Hibernate Save Entity to Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, crud

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPvxC.png) is my project structure:

I'm trying to save a Patient Entity to my database using hibernate:

PatientController.java

```
@RestController
public class PatientController {

    @Autowired
    PatientRepository patientRepository;

    @GetMapping("/patients")
    public List<Patient> getPatients(){

        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("/com/nbu/projects/dentistappointmentsys/hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();

        //Add new Patient object
        Patient p1 = new Patient();
        p1.setEmail("lokesh@mail.com");
        p1.setFirstName("lokesh");
        p1.setLastName("gupta");
        p1.setPassword("gupta123");


        //Save the patient in database
        session.save(p1);

        session.flush();
        session.close();

        return patientRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Patient.java

```
@Entity
public class Patient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    String firstName;

    String lastName;

    String email;

    String password;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Patient(){}

    public Patient(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {

        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

PatientRepository

public interface PatientRepository extends JpaRepository {
}

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dentist-appointment-sys</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.nbu.projects.dentistappointmentsys.models.Patient"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil

```
public class HibernateUtil
{
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
    {
        try {

            return new Configuration().configure("/com/nbu/projects/dentistappointmentsys/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

        } catch (Throwable ex) {

            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

In the fron end I have an http get like so:

```
  public getPatients(): Observable<Patient[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get('patients');
  }
```

So far I was able to read my Patient data from my db, but now that I've tried to update the db I get the [This Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGqA9.png)

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong, since I'm new to hibernate and I'm probably mistaking in my configuration etc..

Comment: check if the config.xml is in the classpath

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm not sure I understand how to check that.. My hibernate.cfg.xml is located in com/nbu/projects/dentistappointmentsys..

Answer (score 0):

Error says it all

Not able to locate hibernate.cfg.xml

so the problem is in this line

```
return new Configuration().configure("/com/nbu/projects/dentistappointmentsys/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

As far as I can see your HibernateUtils is in same place where hibernate.cfg.xml is

so just try

```
return new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

and it should work

getting file reference works **relatively**.

you have to start from **source file** where you are accessing your file and all way to **target file**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I changed it, but still get the same error: message: "Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]"

Comment: This might help https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/location-of-the-hibernate-cfg-xml-file-closed/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving my hibernate.cgf.xml to src/main/resources. To anybody who is having the same issue - check if after you compile the hibernate config file shows up in target/classes, as it should if you've placed it under resources

Answer (score 0):

You can paste your "hibernate.cfg.xml" file to the src\main\resources\hibernate.cfg.xml:

Then in the HibernateUtil file,please change as below:
return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();